# How to make batch close his window why app is still running?

Tags: windows, batch-file, window

I have code

> eclipse -clean

in batch file

> clean.bat

and the console stays open until i close eclipse.

P.S. I know I can create shortcut/link to don't have that problem, but I'm not interested in that. I want to execute some extra code from batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
start eclipse -clean
```

or, if you're using some path to Eclipse (and must quote the invocation):

```
start "" "eclipse" -clean
```